# typedef - does not name a type

Tags: c, typedef

i have two headers

in header “BinTree.h":

```
typedef struct node {
    ElemType data;
    struct node *lchild;
    struct node *rchild;
}BTNode;
```

in header "Queue.h"(which includes BinTree.h):

```
typedef BTNode* Dataype;
```

at compiling the compilor said:
     error: ‘BTNode’ does not name a type

What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing that we can see here is wrong. Can we see more of `Queue.h`? Maybe the inclusion of `BinTree.h` is conditional?

Comment: You should read the pre-processor output of the stage when you're trying to build the file that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include `BinTree.h` in `Queue.h` before the declaration?

Or have you `.cpp` (or moral equivalent) include it beforehand

**EDIT FOR CDT**

Forward declarations are the answer.

As you did not post the code it is difficult to tell.

But I would hazzard a guess here

```
typedef struct node BTNode;
```

whould hit the ticket in `Queue.h`

Comment: There is mutual header inclusion in these two header files, and I declared pragma once in both header files, anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have mutual inclusion you need a forward declaration of your node type. Add this before the `typedef`: `typedef struct node BTnode;`